# Data Table transfer to Model then to the view

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Ok so after alot of research i have concluded that passing a data table to a view is a bad idea ,so how do i pass my data table to a Model and then be able to access each row and column  in the view?Sorry i am new to MVC

I start with a simple SQL statement

```
StringBuilder sbSQL = new StringBuilder();
        //// define a list of CustomerModel objects
        DataSet tempDS = new DataSet();

        //string xSQL = "SELECT PropertyAddress,PropertyTypeDesc,PropertyID FROM KDOR_vwPropertyGeneral ORDER BY PropertyAddress";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter DbCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
        string sqlWhereCont = " WHERE ";
        sbSQL.Append("SELECT ");
        sbSQL.Append("PropertyAddress As PropertyAddress,");
        sbSQL.Append("PropertyTypeDesc As PropertyTypeDesc,");
        sbSQL.Append("PropertyID as PropertyID");
        sbSQL.Append(" FROM [KDOR_vwPropertyGeneral] ");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Address))
        {
            sbSQL.Append(sqlWhereCont + "(PropertyAddress) LIKE '" + user.Address + "%'");
            sqlWhereCont = "AND ";
        }
        sbSQL.Append(" ORDER BY ");
        sbSQL.Append(" PropertyAddress ");



        string MyConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WLConnection"].ConnectionString;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection cnn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sbSQL.ToString(), cnn);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 30000;
        DbCmd.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

move the data to a DataSet and Data Table

```
DbCmd.Fill(tempDS, "ResultSet");
        DataTable resultSet = tempDS.Tables["ResultSet"];
```

Add items to Model

```
 var vm = new List<BedroomModel>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in tempDS.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            vm.Add(new BedroomModel {PropertyAdd  = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString() });
            vm.Add(new BedroomModel { PropertyDesc = dr.ItemArray[1].ToString() });
            vm.Add(new BedroomModel { PropertyID = dr.ItemArray[2].ToString() });
        }
```

Now how to i Access each Item and loop through them in a view? Cause i get an error here is a look at my view

```
@model DataBaseTest.Models.BedroomModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Result";
}

 <h2>Result</h2>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Result";
}

<table border ="1">
<thead>
  @*  <tr>
    @foreach (var col in Model.Columns) {
        <th>
            @col.ColumnName
        </th>
    }
    </tr>*@
    <tr>
        <th>Property Address</th>
        <th>Property Description</th>
        <th>Property ID</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

@foreach (var item in Model.PropertyAdd)
 {         
  <tr>


      <td>@Model.PropertyAdd</td> 

  </tr> 
  }     
 </tbody>
```

```
Model
namespace DataBaseTest.Models
  {
  public class BedroomModel
    {
      public string Address { get; set; }
      public string PropertyAdd { get; set; }
      public string PropertyID { get; set; }
      public string PropertyDesc { get; set; }



       public IEnumerable<BedroomModel> BedroomModels { get; set; }
    }
```

}

Again Sorry i am new to MVC
Any advice Would be Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling your view that it should look for a single `BedroomModel` object, when you actually want to pass it a `List<BedroomModel>` object.

```
@model List<DataBaseTest.Models.BedroomModel>
```

As a result, your `Model` property will be the list itself, so your `foreach` loop only needs to loop through the `Model`, not `Model.BedroomModels`.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{         
    <tr>
        <td>@item.PropertyAdd</td>
        <td>@item.PropertyDesc</td>
        <td>@item.PropertyID</td>
    </tr> 
}
```

Because of this change, you can remove the `BedroomModels` property from your `BedroomModel` class.

```
public class BedroomModel
{
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string PropertyAdd { get; set; }
  public string PropertyID { get; set; }
  public string PropertyDesc { get; set; }
}
```

That would fix your problem, but I also noticed that when populating your `vm` list, you are adding three items into the List, where you should only be adding one `BedroomModel` object. Your `foreach` loop should look like this:

```
var vm = new List<BedroomModel>();
foreach (DataRow dr in tempDS.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    vm.Add(new BedroomModel 
    {
        PropertyAdd  = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString(),
        PropertyDesc = dr.ItemArray[1].ToString(),
        PropertyID = dr.ItemArray[2].ToString()
    };
}
```

You must also make sure that you are sending the ViewModel into the View. Your Action should return:

```
return View(vm);
```

Comment: This will solve your problem. On another note, look into using Entity Framework instead of using raw SQL commands. It is a much better and more reliable way of dealing with Database data.

Comment: i still come up with a Null in Model when i do this

Comment: Are you including the model in your View call? Your Action's return function should say: return View(vm);

Comment: ah i got it i had to return the list to the view Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your view at the top.

```
@model DataBaseTest.Models.BedroomModel
```

This will make the view a strongly typed view. Meaning that it knows what model it will be using to display the data and what properties are available.

Then assign your collection in your controller method prior to your view rendering.

I edited this portion. I just now noticed that you were adding a new object for each property instead of assigning the properties to one object and then adding them. Then you will get a null reference.

```
public ActionResult MyView()
{
    BedroomModel lModel = new BedroomModel();
    lModel.BedroomModels = new List<BedroomModels>();

    DataSet tempDS = CallToBLLOrDAL(); //Do what you need to do to get your data.

    //Assign your values to the ViewModel (Aka lModel in this instance).
    foreach (DataRow dr in tempDS.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        //I am unsure exactly why you are calling ItemArray and adding a new Model for each column.
        //Your way.
        lModel.BedroomModels.Add(new BedroomModel { PropertyAdd = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString() });
        lModel.BedroomModels.Add(new BedroomModel { PropertyDesc = dr.ItemArray[1].ToString() });
        lModel.BedroomModels.Add(new BedroomModel { PropertyID = dr.ItemArray[2].ToString() });

        //Try this
        lModel.BedroomModels.Add(new BedroomModel { PropertyAdd = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString(), PropertyDesc = dr.ItemArray[1].ToString(), PropertyID = dr.ItemArray[2].ToString()});
    }
    return View(lModel);
}
```

Then in your view.

```
@foreach (BedroomModel lBedroomModel in Model.BedroomModels)
{
    <td>
        @lBedroomModel.PropertyAdd
    </td>
}
```

Debugging tips.

You can set a break point in your view inside of your foreach. Drag your Model down to your watches. You should be able to see the population of your model and all of the values within the current scope.

I am unsure why the coloring is off on the view code snippet.

Let me know what you think.

Please set as answer if this helps.

Comment: It comes back with a null, but i updated my view model maybe there is something wrong @Andrew Leon

Comment: I did notice that your code above does not specifically assign the values to any collection. It just says var vm = new List<BedroomModel>(); I edited my answer above.

Comment: Sorry, it took a minute for me to write that out.

Comment: how do i assign the values?